# NameError: name '<name>' is not defined, when using % format syntax for strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, formatting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Simon\Downloads\rpgbs.py", line 72, in <module>
    print("%(chara) has %(health) HP." % {chara:names[k], health:str(health[k])})
NameError: name 'chara' is not defined
```

I get the above error when running this code. The relevant sections are below.

When I run `print(names["Enemy"], health["Enemy"])` on its own, that seems to work just fine. But when I use formatting syntax (from my understanding `print("%(author) likes spam.") % {author:"Simon"}`), it goes right down the drain. Does it have anything to do with the fact that I'm trying to iterate it?

```
names = {'Player' : str(input("What's your name, hero?: ")),                                        
          'Enemy' : str(input("And who will you be duelling with?"))}
if names["Enemy"]=="UNDERTALE":
    names["Enemy"]=namechoose(["Froggit", "Sans", "Flowey", "Chara", "ASRIEL DREEMUR", "Toriel", "Undyne", "Mettaton"],1)
elif names["Enemy"]=="POKEMON":
    names["Enemy"]=namechoose(["Charizard","Blastoise", "Venusaur", "Arceus", "Dialga", "Palkia", "Groudon"],1)
elif names["Enemy"]=="DRAGON QUEST":
    names["Enemy"]=namechoose(["Corvus", "Aquila", "Hootingham-Gore", "Goresby-Purrvis", "Stella", "The Almighty", "Slime", "Metal Slime"],1)    

startinghealth=int(input("How much health do you wish to start with? 150 is recommended."))         
health = {'Player' : startinghealth,                                                                
          'Enemy' : startinghealth}                                                                 


while health["Enemy"]>0 and health["Player"]>0:
    for k in names:
        print(names[k], health[k])
        print("%(chara) has %(health) HP." % {chara:names[k], health:str(health[k])})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed s character after the brace, also you use chara as variable in this line not as string key for hash.
That why you have that error that say that you don't have chara variable defined. Correct line should look like this:
`print("%(chara)s has %(health)s HP." % {'chara':names[k], 'health':str(health[k])})`